# Sending HTTP/2 request to Apple Push Notification Service using HttpClient, Client Certificate and WinHttpHandler raises HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications, dotnet-httpclient, http2

I am trying to write some code to send a push notification to an iPhone using C# .NET and HttpClient over HTTP with client certificate authentication.

Code compiles but always yields a:

HttpRequestException with Message "Error while copying content to a stream."

InnerException IOException Message "The write operation failed, see inner exception."

InnerException WinHttpException Message "{"Error 12152 calling WinHttpWriteData, 'The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response'."}"

I am looking for why the code is failing?

Is it possible to debu/troubleshoot this in some way?

Here is my code

```
class Program {
    private const string cert = "MIINKwI....<hidden>";
    private const string certpw = "password";
    private const string devicetoken = "921c95b6494828f973512f2327478b0<hidden>";
    private const string bundleid = "se.jensolsson.testapp";

    private static HttpClient client = null;
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        try {

            byte[] certificateData = Convert.FromBase64String(cert);
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData, certpw, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

            string url = "https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/";

            string payload = @"{""aps"":{""alert"":""Test""}}";

            var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            if (client == null)
                client = new HttpClient(handler);

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url + devicetoken)) {
                var messageGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                request.Version = new Version("2.0");
                request.Content = new StringContent(payload);
                request.Headers.Add("apns-id", messageGuid);
                request.Headers.Add("apns-push-type", "alert");
                request.Headers.Add("apns-priority", "10");
                request.Headers.Add("apns-topic", bundleid);


                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)) {
                    HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    string reasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
                    bool success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException anu) { }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe) { }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre) { }
        catch (TaskCanceledException tce) { }
        catch (Exception e) { }        
    }
}
```

**EDIT** @jdweng actually tried Wireshark but since it is over SSL and encrypted I would expect it to be unreadable from Wireshark? What I can see is that the connection is reset from our client, must be done by the underlying framework.

[image: Wireshark]

**EDIT 2:**
Investigating further. Tried to connect to an open HTTP2 capable web server. I used https://nghttp2.org/ as an example.

1. Replaced url line to `string url = "https://nghttp2.org/";`
2. replaced request line to `using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)) {`.

A very interesting finding is that even though i send a HTTP/2 request and it seem to give a reply, looking at the response object, **Version is set to 1.1**.

If I also remove the `handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);` line and retry, looking at the response object, **Version is correctly set to 2.0**.

So it seem like WinHttpHandler drops HTTP/2 support as soon as a client certificate is added to the handler.

**EDIT 3:**
I now assume this is a bug in the framework and I have posted a bug report here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40794

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the status in the response.  Normally 200 OK and errors are 400/500.  I'm suspecting a TLS 1.2 issue.   TLS 1.0/1.1 was discontinued by many servers in June this year and lots of people are having issues.  But not sure.  Your error indicates you probably got a 200 OK and the data in the response is not recognizable.  But not sure.  That is why sniffer results are important.

Comment: Hi 

Is there any way to implement apns push notification in Dot.Net using WinHttpHandler on framework 4.6 ?
I am getting error "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that this is not supported.
Mainly because of missing functionality in the Windows version. According to a comment in github in the corefx team this should work from Windows version 2004, build 19573+ [github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/42888#issuecomment-676534416). The problem with this version is that it is not released yet and there is no plan on when it will be.

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same issue now. I am using .net framework 4.8 and WinHttpHandler and I am getting the same error as you did: 

WinHttpException Message "{"Error 12152 calling WinHttpWriteData, 'The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response'."}"

I tried using other open source libraries like PushSharp and it looks like they do not currently support Http/2 and dotApns do not support Certificate based authentication for .net framework

Comment: Have not solved it yet but I would expect it to be fixed in a future version of Windows. As this was some time ago maybe it works on newer version....

Comment: It looks like the issue still exists. I am using Windows 10 OS version: 21H2 and OS Build version: 19044. Your comment mentioned that build version has to be 19573+. Does that mean the OS version 21H2 also has to be on build version 19573+?

Comment: @marak i guess that is the case but I dont know how build numbers between windows versions work. One would think enough time should have passed